# Target non-nested div based on class

Tags: css, html

I have a page with code that looks like this:

```
<div class="shop-main">
  <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
<div class="social-tabs">
  <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

On mobile I need to change `social-tabs` to `display:none;` on every page that contains `shop-main`. However, as you can see, they are not nested thus I cannot write:

```
.shop-main .social-tabs{ 
   display:none;
}
```

How would I change the css for only the pages containing the class `shop-main`?

Note: I omitted the media query above but I am targeting devices in this range:

```
@media (min-width:641px) and (max-width:980px){ /* CSS */  }
```

Also I cannot nest the divs or use other divs on the page.

Comment: just make a media query with the screen-size ranges of the mobile devices you target and set there social tabs to `display:none;`

Comment: @SvenBieder - I only want the `social-tabs` effected on the page with `shop-main` not all of the pages. That method would effect all other pages that do not contain `shop-main`.

Comment: I can't imagine your complete page structures. You only have given a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the sibling selector in your media query:

```
.shop-main + .social-tabs { 
   display:none;
}
```